# OnSelectedIndexChanged not working first selection, but will on subsequent selections

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a listbox in a datagrid that is supposed to update upon selection change, and it does, but not on first try. only after it has posted back, after the first time it is clicked will it work as intended. any help appreciated.

Here is the front end portion of the datagrid with the listbox.

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Qty">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" CssClass="grid" />
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="true" CssClass="grid" width="30" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="lstQty" rows="1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lstQtyUpdate" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Here is the page load section:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            LoadCart()
            cartList.Columns(0).Visible = False
            If (cartList.Items.Count = 0) Then
                cartList.Visible = False
                lblEmptyMsg.Visible = True
            Else
                cartList.Visible = True
                lblEmptyMsg.Visible = False
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Errorlog(ex, "Cart.Page_Load()")
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is the sub that is called with the onselectedindexchanged:

```
Protected Sub lstQtyUpdate(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim lb As New ListBox
    lb = CType(sender, ListBox)
    Dim thisID As String = lb.ClientID
    Dim oiQty As Integer = ComFunctions.ConvertToInt(lb.SelectedItem.Value)
    Dim oiID As Integer = 0
    For Each item As DataGridItem In cartList.Items
        lb = CType(item.FindControl("lstQty"), ListBox)
        If (thisID = lb.ClientID) Then
            oiID = ComFunctions.ConvertToInt(item.Cells(0).Text)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next.....
```

Here is the binding for the datagrid, which may be the culprit.

```
Private Sub cartList_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles cartList.ItemDataBound
    Try
        Dim rbd As ImageButton
        Dim lst As ListBox
        Dim id As Integer = 0
        Dim evTitle As String = String.Empty
        Dim evImage As String = String.Empty
        Dim capacity As Integer = 0
        Dim soldseats As Integer = 0
        Dim seatsleft As Integer = 0
        Dim evdate As String = String.Empty
        Dim evtimestart As String = String.Empty
        Dim evtimeend As String = String.Empty
        Dim EditLink As String = String.Empty
        Dim DeletedLink As String = String.Empty
        If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Or (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then
            id = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "oi_id")
            evTitle = ComFunctions.ConvertToStr(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "title"))
            evImage = ComFunctions.ConvertToStr(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "image"))
            evdate = ComFunctions.ConvertToDate(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "eventsdatestart"))
            capacity = ComFunctions.ConvertToStr(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "capacity"))
            seatsleft = (capacity - soldseats)
            evtimestart = ComFunctions.Format_Time((DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "eventsdatestart")))
            evtimeend = ComFunctions.Format_Time((DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "eventsdateend")))
            Dim obj_DATA_Capacity As New DATA_Events()
            soldseats = obj_DATA_Capacity.GetSeatsSold(id)
            e.Item.Cells(0).Text = id
            e.Item.Cells(1).Text = evTitle & "<br />" & evdate & " " & evtimestart & " - " & evtimeend
            e.Item.Cells(2).Text = "<img src=""" & AppSettings("Events_ImagePath") & "/Thumb/" & evImage & """ width=""100"" />"
            e.Item.Cells(3).Text = "$" & ComFunctions.ConvertToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "oi_price"), 2)
            lst = CType(e.Item.FindControl("lstQty"), ListBox)
            If seatsleft > 0 Then
                'lst.Items.Add(0)
                For I = 1 To seatsleft
                    lst.Items.Add(I)
                Next
            End If
            lst.ID = id
            lst.SelectedValue = ComFunctions.ConvertToInt(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "oi_qty"))
            rbd = CType(e.Item.FindControl("DeleteThis"), ImageButton)
            rbd.CommandArgument = id
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Errorlog(ex, "quickCart.cartList_ItemDataBound()")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it does not work the first time, by the way, what does "not work" actually mean? But apart from that, your way to get the text of the first cell in the current `DataGridItem`  is odd.

This is much more directly:

```
Dim lb = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
Dim item = DirectCast(lb.NamingContainer, DataGridItem)
Dim oiID = Int32.Parse(item.Cells(0).Text)
```

Maybe it helps also get it working.

Comment: that certainly is more direct and much appreciated. still having issue though, but let me explain more clearly. When you change the selection of the listbox, the page flickers like it was calling the sub for the OnSelectedIndexChanged however, it resets to the original values as they were upon page load. By making the selection again it updates properly with no page flicker. Additionally, i experimented with adding a button that called a blank sub. when i click that button, the page flickers and the listboxes operate as they are supposed to.

Comment: obviously though, having to click the button is not suitable. not sure why it isn't working on its own. oddly the other controls, buttons, not interacting with the datagrid work fine.

Comment: I don not understand why you are using `DataBinder.Eval`in `ItemDataBound`. You can use the underlying DataSource there directly via `e.Item.DataItem`.

Comment: I removed the databinder.eval, yes that is much cleaner. Thank you. Still getting the odd issue of the listbox not updating upon the first change of the selected item but still working on the 2nd attempt and subsequent also so i am really confused.